# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined and m.ban

Tags: javascript, function, discord, discord.js, typeerror

So I asked a question like this before sadly no one could figure it out so I come here. So there is a error catcher in the code if a command or function doesn't work. I have been trying to figure it out for ages any help will be great. So it says this

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

but by auto catcher says this

`An error occurred while running the command: TypeError: m.ban is not a function`

here is the code for the actual project in itself.

```
  this.client.guilds.cache.forEach(m => {
   m.ban(argUser.id, `"${reason}" - ${msgObject.author.tag}`);
 });
 msgObject.channel.send(
   `Banned ${argUser.tag} in all the servers :triumph::relieved:! All done!`
 );
  return;
}
```

so not sure, thanks!|

here

```
      msg.react("").then(m => {
        msg.react("❎");
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
          if (
            reaction.emoji.name === "" &&
            user.id === msgObject.author.id &&
            reaction.message === msg
          ) {
            msgObject.reply(
              "Coolio :joy::joy:! Let's ban em' from everything! :gun:"
            );
            this.client.guilds.cahce.forEach(m => {
              m.ban(argUser.id, `"${reason}" - ${msgObject.author.tag}`);
              });
            msgObject.channel.send(
              `Banned ${argUser.tag} in all the servers :triumph::relieved:! All done!`
            );
          }
        };
        msg.awaitReactions(filter, {});
      });
```

Comment: if `this.client.guilds.cache` is undefined, then `m` in the for each loop is also undefined, which means `m.ban` is also undefined. Your first--and perhaps only--problem is figuring out why `this.client.guilds.cache` is undefined.

Comment: Where does your client.guilds.cache come from? I recommend running a debugger, investigating why you don’t have Access to the Cache.

Comment: @e.Fro I added it to the main question.

Comment: You made a typo at `this.client.guilds.cahce` in your second snippet. I guess you mean `cache`

Comment: @Seblor Thanks! Sadly it wasn't it. Still has the same issue, thanks for pointing it out.